# chef-client 16 does not report how many resources got updated

Tags: chef-infra

I am using chef-client 16.8 on Ubuntu Focal,
just found that its output is quite different with previous one,

```
# chef-client -o some_cookbook -l info
...
[2021-01-14T09:45:49+00:00] INFO: Skipping removal of unused files from the cache
[2021-01-14T09:45:49+00:00] INFO: Running report handlers
[2021-01-14T09:45:49+00:00] INFO: Report handlers complete
[2021-01-14T09:45:49+00:00] INFO: Chef::Compliance::Runner#enabled?: Chef InSpec profiles? false
[2021-01-14T09:45:49+00:00] INFO: Chef::Compliance::Runner#enabled?: audit cookbook? false
[2021-01-14T09:45:49+00:00] INFO: Sending resource update report (run-id: 27e9fbeb-118d-4fc3-8de3-8f5f32eae15d)
```

Previous one(chef-client 13.12.3) is like this:

```
...
  * execute[echo] action run (skipped due to only_if)
  * file[/tmp/etc/apache2/certs/.changed] action nothing (skipped due to action :nothing)

Running handlers:
Running handlers complete
Chef Client finished, 0/13 resources updated in 06 seconds
```

Obviously, chef-client 16 does not show color report, nor statistics of how many resources got updated.

Is there anyone know how to set chef-client 16 to show which resources got changed?

Comment: You're only getting the logger somehow you need to `--force-formatter` or look into your client.rb settings.  See https://github.com/chef/chef/pull/9751 as well.

Comment: @lamont thank you, nice! let me install a chef 16 and have a try. I have thought no one have this issue and not expected a answer.

Comment: @lamont this works like a charm

Comment: @lamont could you please post a simple answer? I will accept that as final answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chef 16.0 changed the way that the logger and formatter works:

https://github.com/chef/chef/pull/9751

This was done to address the extremely common issue that people have with the output magically changing from the formatter to the logger when piped through something like grep:

```
chef-client | grep "resources updated"
```

(In the absence of any other configuration not doing the pipe usually prints that "resources updated" line, while piping to grep loses the tty and magic in chef-client automatically switches output to the logger which no longer logs the line)

It was impossible to fix this and maintain backwards compatibility.  A lot of work went into making sure that config.rb settings were obeyed, cli settings could override them, and that command-line run chef-client would also log to /var/log/messages.

It is still not possible to have tty output in the formatter output and logger output going to a log file at the same time.

For users that had logging configured in client.rb then the `--force-formatter` option may be required now:

```
chef-client --force-formatter
```

This will typically also log to the logfile, but will switch the output to the formatter, which if the user has setup logging to a logfile in the log format will cause a mixture of formats, which is not really what anyone wants, but fixing that is the subject of the discussion in the end of that pull request above.  Since Chef 17 is likely to be dominated by Ruby 3.0 fixing it is unlikely that bug will get fixed before Chef 18 though.

Answer (score 1):

i am running chef 16.9.20 and i do not have that issue. after chef-client run i get

```sh
Chef Infra Client finished, 15/126 resources updated in 36 seconds
```

Comment: thank you, seems no one else encountered this issue. I am going to close this question.